# Sql error in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here I joined 2 tables addprojects and users. But It show me error. How can I fix it?

```
$test= addproject::select('addprojects.id','addprojects.proj_name',DB::raw("DATEDIFF(addprojects.proj_starts,addprojects.proj_end)AS Days"))
                                ->join('user', 'users.emp_id', '=', 'addprojects.emp_id')
                                ->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: have you checked the compiled sql?

Comment: I checked this....

Answer (score -1):

what the error appeared to you ? 
check this example below, i had done it to join tables :

```
$nextvisits = patients::join('visits', 'visits.patient_id', '=', 'patients.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'visits.user_id')
    ->where('visits.revisit_date','>=',$now_str)
    ->where('patients.clinic_id', $user->clinic_id)
    ->where('visits.clinic_id', $user->clinic_id)
    ->where('visits.active','=','1')
    ->get();
```